# Application heating up and using more cpu percentages in mac

Tags: macos, firefox, heat

As a developer I love to use firefox but it uses more then 50% of cpu and my mac book air becomes hot. I have already tried making hardware render off. still its same issue.

Some times when I use adobe premier its render process eats CPU, sometimes 180% and running this much CPU for longer run is obviously not healthy.

Any workaround

Answer (score 0):

What I found is following.

This step can be used for other cpu incentive applications also.

so, just follow the steps

1. Install cputhrottle

   brew install cputhrottle
2. Open activity monitor 
   ( well, command+space and activity monitor ;) )

Note PID of any process that is taking much cpu resources

on terminal run this command

```
sudo cputhrottle PID 25
```

here 25 is the max percentage you want to allow for this process to take.

terminal will keep continue to run this process so do not close this terminal .

In case of premier, it will take longer then before, but will keep your MAC running at least :)